# Map Fragment Class doesnt infalte! Getting InflateException

Tags: android, google-maps, maven, maps

I am having trouble with my android app.

I am trying to switch between two tabs which one of them should show a Map.
but the thread is exiting with uncaught exception.
When i debug i get this:

> Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

I looked at every possible google search result but I coudlnt find the answer.

this is my mapclass

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview_tab, container, false);

        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

//         Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(47.223065, 8.816511), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);



        return v;
    }



}
```

this is my xml file mapview_tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this dependency i added to the pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and here are some important code writings out of my manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="dsvfdfsAdsfasdfcvdasVGJfsDSSDzcfdASWD"/>


<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

the googleplaylibraray jar file is a "non-runtime maven dependenciy"

I HOPE SOMEONE CAN HELP ME OUT!!

kidn regards,

trash

------EDIT-----------

logcat:

> VFY: unable to resolve static field 1308 (MapAttrs) in
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
>
> VFY: replacing opocode 0x62 at 0x000e
>
> Shutting down VM
>
> threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b81700)

EDIT 2 -----------------------------

NEW XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/MapView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

MAP CLASS

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview_tab, container, false);
        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.MapView);

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(47.223065, 8.816511), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return v;

    }

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
05-13 14:47:50.189: D/AbsListView(16376): unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-13 14:47:51.179: D/AbsListView(16376): onDetachedFromWindow
05-13 14:48:20.009: D/AndroidRuntime(16376): Shutting down VM
05-13 14:48:20.009: W/dalvikvm(16376): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b81700)
```

after clicking on the MAP TAB this is the last I get, then my phones freezes.

Comment: post your Logcat please..

Comment: Is it possible that I have problems with the google play library? that it doenst work because it isnt right imported?

Comment: Try it after importing google play services..

Answer (score 0):

Post device version also it may be due to extends fragment class, if you are using devices for testing with lower version you have extend

```
public class MapFragment extends
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: thats not it. my other tab also extends from Fragment and it works fine. having a galaxy s3 with andorid 4.3

Answer (score 0):

check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2
      ---guidlines by google

way to go:--> use mapfragmet instead of mapview....

**update**

For Map class

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview_tab, container, false);

        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: maybe I do it wrong? I changed the xml file like its on the link described. but how do I have to change my .java file? can you guide me through this?

Comment: @tritrotrash every thing is there in the link

Comment: my class extends from FRAGMENT, so its not an activity.

Comment: thats fine just inflate the mapfragments xml file in your fragments class

Comment: please paste the exact logcat error and update the question according to new implementations..cant help without it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52602/discussion-between-sagar-g-and-tritrotrash)